# How to place More than one image on top of a material?

Tags: image

I have more than one images that I want to put on top of a material.

Most tutorials shows how to put only 1 image.

And if using node, I have to choose the strength between the image and the texture. While I need both of them to have the factor of strength of 1. Thus node seems not the way. I dunno.

And, is there a way to  add images to a material and them position them on the 3dviewport easily?

Comment: Can u please elaborate or demonstrate more clearly what you want to achieve? ITs kind of hard just from your text to understand,

Comment: MMm... I have a tshirt object. I already applied a white material on the mesh. But I want also to add more image details of a logo, buttons, and stitches.  And them position them at the correct place respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with the material ok. First of all import a base color image if it is there then use the brush image aka button, stictches and else,. make sure this brush image have repeat in the node set to clip, so it won't repeat, otherwise you will get repetition and won't get desired location.
[image]

make  sure the brush image have transparency of the part you don't want it, look at the image in image viewer above it is transparent and only has those white pattern. connect this alpha to factor of mix node and so on.

Secondly make the node setup as the image 2 shown
[image]

You can see in the node editor I use a different UV map for the brush object because it will scale and move and you don't want that to happen to your base texture. here is the UV stack I am showing
[image]

Now fourth thing you want your UV to be movable ? add a modifier to the mesh of yours called UV Project and
select the brush UV u want to use. And add a new empty to scene and on the modifier of the original mesh add this empty to the bottom option as in the image
[image]

Voila now when u move the empty, your UV will move and so it will affect actual texture. scale it rotate move all works you can also go in UV edit mode while ur active uv is brush-UV
and scale there too .

Repeat the process for the other parts. But Tbh I recommend texture painting for these kind of stuff. But you asked for it so here it is all. Good luck
Here is the blend file I can't share these textures, cuz they are paid but you can add ur image in node editor.
To add more brush just do this in node editor.
[image]

Here is the blend file without textures   https://www.mediafire.com/file/ca6iwldztgatbrw/Movable_Texture_Overlay.blend/file